# How do I execute a jar from inside a jar?

Tags: java, jar

I plan to execute a jar command using a jar that is included in another jar.

The command will automatically obfuscate a Java jar file using code similar to:

```
public void obfuscate()
{
    try
    {
        String jre = "\"" + System.getProperty("java.home") + "\\bin\\javaw.exe" + "\"";
        String jar = " -jar";
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { jre, jar.trim(), "/lib/allatori.jar /lib/config.xml" });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`allatori.jar` file is included in my `main.jar` file as a resource. `config.xml` file is also included.

How can I run my command so that it executes the included jar file?

Folder structure of **main.jar**:

```
- main.jar
  |
  |- main_class.class
  |- lib/
      |- allatori.jar
      |- config.xml
      |- jarToObfuscate.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will certainly have to unpack it outside the jar before running it.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Copy it outside, create a classloader, find the class you want to start with, and off you go. In place while it's still there? well, you'd have to write your own code to pull the class files out of the embedded jar file and make them available to a class loader, probably you'd have to write it from scratch.

Comment: *"probably you'd have to write it from scratch."*  See for e.g. [Fat Jar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/) which *"The One-JAR option integrates a specialised Class-Loader .. which handles jar-files inside a jar."* & [JarClassLoader](http://www.jdotsoft.com/JarClassLoader.php) *"The class loader to load classes, native libraries and resources from the top JAR and from JARs inside the top JAR."* just a few of the top hits on a major search engine..

Comment: Easiest way would probably to create a copy of the jar programaticaly, then run it with the Runtime.exec, and delete it after. What do you think of that?